# Coprimality of quotient ideals in primary decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

The primary decompositions states that in a Noetherian ring $R$, every ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ can be decomposed as an intersection of finitely many primary ideals
$$\mathfrak{a}=\cap_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{q}_i.$$
Let $(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{q})=\{r\in R: r\mathfrak{q}\subset \mathfrak{a}\}$ be the ideal quotient of $\mathfrak{a}$ over $\mathfrak{q}$.
Then is it true that the quotients $(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{q}_i)$ are coprime in the sense that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{q}_i) = R\ ?$$

This question is motivated by the primary decomposition for a linear space acted upon by a matrix, where $R$ is specialized to be a polynomial ring over a field, $\mathfrak{a}$ generated by the minimal polynomial, and the $\mathfrak{q}_i$'s generated by the primary components of the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In the ring $k[x,y]$, consider $I=(x^2,xy)=(x)\cap (x^2, y)=P\cap Q$. We have $(I:Q)=P$ and $(I:P)=(x,y)=M$. Note that $P+M=M$.

Basically, the problem is "embedded primes": one of the primary ideals is associated with a prime that is *contained in* the prime ideal associated with one of the other primary ideals.